# Maven Fatal Error because of cucumber-junit dependency

Tags: maven, cucumber

Something very strange is happening.
I have the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The project compiles perfectly.
But as soon as I change the cucumber version in this dependency to 1.2.6 I get an error when compling the progect:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gp-it-test-product: Fatal error compiling
```

I also attempted to use the most recent cucumber version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I got the same error. Why is this happening? Version 1.2.5 works OK

Comment: You are importing the dependency as pom type. That seems wrong. v1.2.6 is a relocation notification release. The combination of using pom+relocation may break. Can you remove the type?

Comment: There's no difference. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It was moved to another group `io.cucumber` after version `1.2.5` [check the maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.6)

Comment: I know. Let's assume that's the reason, but then why I get the same error when I try to use the the most recent dependency with correct group.

Comment: what is the configuration of your `maven-compiler-plugin`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally solved this. The problem was not in maven, but in cucumber. It appeared that some old packages that I was using in my code disappeared, so I had to change all old imports to new ones and also make some other changes in accordance with the new version to make it work. Nullpointer exception that I posted was due to changed package of Scenario class.